# Meaning of "take the way"

Tags: meaning, idioms

Does the expression *take the way* signify that you take a particular route with a specific destination? The sentence I came up with is

> He **took the way** to the stadium.

Is that correct?

Comment: Why "way"? Generally, you wouldn't use 'way' to describe where someone went.

Comment: I agree. It seems like it's translated from another language, I was just wondering if it's a valid expression in English. And I meant I came across this expression, not 'came up with'

Comment: It's probably *never* correct. I might almost be okay with it in a sentence like "After deliberating at the crossroads for some time, he took the way to the stadium". But I don't like it. People do say [He went the way of xxxxx](http://www.google.com/search?q="he%20went%20the%20way"&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1951,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en), but this is invariably figuration (a common one being where *xxxxxx=all flesh*, meaning *He died*). I think OP's usage may have been more acceptable historically, but not today.

Comment: 'He took the wrong way to the stadium' is certainly found.

Comment: @Barrie: But that would rarely be used to imply that the right way was to go somewhere completely different. It would normally mean he was going to the stadium anyway, but didn't take the best route to get there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OED has

> 29.
>   a.   take the way n. ... To enter on and follow the route leading to a specified place.

I live in the US, and find this usage not out of the ordinary.  I certainly do not agree that it is "never correct" as some of the UK commenters do.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work:

[Google results](http://www.google.com/search?q="take+the+way+to")

but could be considered out of date.

[Ngram:](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+the+way+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

[image: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+the+way+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3]

Answer (score 1):

I find "take the *adjective* way" normal - the easy way, the wrong way, the quick way, the pretty way - but not "take the way".

On the other hand, "make one's way" is common, but has a connotation of it being more than just a journey: an effort, or a great endeavour.